# Redimensionar Div con mousemove

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap, css3

Tengo un problema con el div al momento de agrandarlo no se por que razón da un salto y no se va agrandando conforme se mueve el puntero en la pantalla. 
Estoy utilizando html5, CSS3, bootstrap y JS con jQuery.
Esto se encuentra dentro de una tabla.
Este es mi código.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var resizeHandle = document.getElementById('ctr_jose_right');
  var box = document.getElementById('tarea_jose');

  resizeHandle.addEventListener('mousedown', initialiseResize, false);

  function initialiseResize(e) {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', startResizing, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', stopResizing, false);
  }

  function startResizing(e) {
    //Obtiene la posicion del mouse en la pantalla
    var width = e.clientX;

    var medida = box.style.width = (e.clientX) + 'px';

  }

  function stopResizing(e) {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', startResizing, false);
    window.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopResizing, false);
  }
});
```

```css
.height-barra {
  height: 2px !important;
}

.circle-bar-left-jose {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #3d6cb2;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  float: left;
}

.circle-bar-right-jose {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #3d6cb2;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
  right: 0px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -15px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="table_right" width="70%" style="vertical-align: text-top; position: absolute;">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Project Manager">
    <div id="tarea_jose" style="width: 450px;">
     <p class="text-center delete-margin-bottom"><span id="porcentaje_planificacion_usuario" class="text-barra">100%</span></p>
  <div id="ctr_jose_left" class="circle-bar-left-jose"></div>
  <div id="ctr_jose_right" class="circle-bar-right-jose"></div>
  <div class="progress height-barra">
    <div id="bar_planificacion_integrante" class="progress-bar barra-planificacion" role="progressbar" style="width: 450px;"></div>
    <div id="bar_planificacion_integrante_faltante" class="progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" style="width: 0px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</span>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Aquí parece que funciona correctamente pero en mi ambiente localhost al momento de arrastrar el puntero sobre el div da un salto y agranda el div aproximadamente 30 o 40 px de más.
La pregunta es ¿De que manera puedo evitar que de ese salto al realizar el resizing del div?
Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás calculando el ancho del elemento de la siguiente forma:

```
var width = e.clientX;
```

Sin embargo, e.clientX devuelve la posición con respecto a la ventana. Tu ancho no debería tener el desplazamiento a la izquierda de tu control:

```
var width = e.clientX - box.offsetLeft;
var medida = box.style.width = width + 'px';
```

De esta forma el ancho de tu control se calculará correctamente.

Un saludo.